# Android Vision OCR reader not able to read font size 8 or below, but mobile camera is capturing with good clarity

Tags: android, text, fonts, size, vision

I am trying to read text from pamphlets or visiting cards using the VISION API. Higher size fonts are detecting well, but with font size 10 or below its not able to detect it. But when i try to capture the image with camera app text is very clear in preview. Do I need to pass extra params to read lower font sizes, and resolution parameters required. Please suggest tips to read lower font sizes(5 to 10). Am curious to know how camera preview showing text and Vision not able to read it. does some thing am missing?

```
mCameraSource =   new CameraSource.Builder(getApplicationContext(),textRecognizer)
                        .setFacing(CameraSource.CAMERA_FACING_BACK)
                        .setRequestedPreviewSize(1280, 1024)
                        .setRequestedFps(2.0f)
                        .setFlashMode(useFlash ?      Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH : null)
                        .setFocusMode(autoFocus ? Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE : null)
                        .build();
```

Due to low points , images are shared at below link.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/adCXK.jpg 
  Few times reading "AXIS BANK LTD","Personal Lonas" and hardly mobile numbers(99499 62941,90309 72768)
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/gc3IZ.jpg
  Few times reading "HDFC BANK", and "Harinathreddy"

Nothing else is reading except what text mentioned under image links.
  Thanks a ton for helping..

Comment: share an image...

Comment: Added images...